# Are default gcc compiler options gcc version specific or OS specific or both?

Tags: c, ubuntu, gcc, default-value, compiler-flags

I am wondering if the default gcc compiler options can vary any if so where I can expect different default compiler options. Do default compiler options vary from one gcc version to another (e.g gcc 4.6 -> gcc 4.8)or are they always the same? Do default compiler options vary from one OS version to another (e.g. Ubuntu 12.04 -> 14.04)?

I expect that default compiler options are different regarding two different OS, like Ubuntu and Debian, right?

Comment: Ubuntu is based on Debian.

Comment: @Olaf ...but Debian rocks ;)

Comment: does this necessarily mean the default compiler options are the same?

Comment: Default gcc options are based on the way gcc is compiled.

Comment: do they in practice differ?

Comment: *Some* default gcc options are based on the way gcc is compiled - Or rather, how you want them when you compile gcc. *Some* others are based on the architecture (obviously - m68k has other options than x86, so defaults are different, too) .

Comment: @tofro Strictly speaking, the (default) architecture of the gcc target is set in compile time too :)

Comment: Both, and they are build-specific, too.  But the default defaults for non-arch-specific options do not generally vary across arches, and the default defaults for most options shared by different compiler versions rarely change across compiler versions.

Comment: One example was that for quite some time `-fnostrength-reduce` *had* to be used to work around a bug in gcc and was thus in practically all defaults. Once the bug was fixed, most distributions dropped that default option

Comment: @EugeneSh. very strictly speaking, that was not part of the question ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can generally expect the default flags to be quite different.  Fortunately, you don't need to know what the flags are, and you don't need to set them.

Ubuntu and Debian are pretty similar, since Ubuntu is so closely based on Debian.  But you will see a variety of different options, since the actual options that GCC uses are fairly technical.  You can see them by running the following:

```
gcc -Q -v -x c -c /dev/null
```

This asks GCC to compile `/dev/null` as a C program (`-x c -c /dev/null`) and print out a bunch of developer info (`-Q -v`).  I ran this with GCC 4.4, 4.6, and 4.8 and got different results.  Here are the differences between the options for 4.4 and 4.6 on my machine:

```
< -falign-loops
< -fargument-alias
> -fdelete-null-pointer-checks
> -fprefetch-loop-arrays
> -fsched-critical-path-heuristic
> -fsched-dep-count-heuristic
> -fsched-group-heuristic
> -fsched-last-insn-heuristic
> -fsched-rank-heuristic
> -fsched-spec-insn-heuristic
> -fshow-column
> -fstrict-volatile-bitfields
> -ftree-forwprop
> -ftree-loop-if-convert
> -ftree-phiprop
> -ftree-pta
> -ftree-slp-vectorize
> -fvar-tracking-assignments
< -mfused-madd
```

Here are the diffs from version 4.6 to 4.8 on my machine:

```
> -faggressive-loop-optimizations
> -fgnu-runtime
> -fgnu-unique
< -finline-functions-called-once
> -finline-atomics
> -fira-hoist-pressure
> -fsync-libcalls
> -ftree-coalesce-vars
< -fvect-cost-model
> -mfxsr
> -mlong-double-80
```

On my machine, GCC uses 80 different options by default when compiling C!  The options will also change when you compile C++ or compile on different platforms.

But that's okay.  You can basically ignore all of these options and just focus on the most important ones, which are the various `-W` warning flags, `-O` optimization flags (which are really just shortcuts for a ton of preselected `-f` flags and a few `-m`—on my computer, `-O2` enables 63 additional flags!), and the `-g` debug data flag.

And of course, the basic flags, like `-std=`, `-c`, `-o`, `-l`, `-I`, etc.

I mean, do you really need to know what `-fbranch-count-reg` does?  Not really.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you take advantage of tools such as `automake` to build the Makefiles for your application. This tool can build the files in different ways depending on environment. Then, within that Makefile, *specify* the options that are important to you: do not leave them to defaults ("to chance").

Comment: The question "as stated," as I read it, was not merely *"do the default options vary?"* As suggested by *"and where can I expect different compiler options?,"* I interpreted the thrust of the question to be: "how can I be sure what will happen in every case?" So, that's how I tried to reply: *(a)* use Automake, and then *(b)* specify everything that is relevant instead of relying on defaults. **Now,** you *know* what will happen, in every case. Users run the `configure && make` procedure that they're well-used to, and you have complete control over what happens.

Comment: OP is asking for _default gcc compiler options_... how on earth can automake change them...?

Comment: Automake allows environment-specific Makefiles to be generated, and these Makefiles, *instead of relying on any defaults,* explicitly specify every compiler-option that is necessary for the proper operation of the software.  I did not address the "literal" question: that had already been done. I attempted to answer the "apparent purpose" of the question: the apparent reason *why* it had been asked. Vote it up or down as you please.